Is it possible to run MANOVA without adjusting the Alpha level?
I have 11 dependent variables and two independent variables. I need to see the differences between the gender and academic level concerning the 10 most frequent grammatical errors and the total number of errors, and I have to see the specific differences between them in each error type. Do I need to correct the alpha level to 0.0045. I am just going to run one MANOVA and then I will check the Tests of Between-Subjects Effects to see the differences.
I am in dire need of guidance

For this, as for any question of adjusting for multiple tests, there is no one right answer. Jacob Cohen said "this is a question on which reasonable people can differ." And, in Statistics as Principled Argument Robert Abelson notes that it is not what you can or can't do, but what you can justify.
If you adjust the p value you control type I error. But, of course, anything that lowers type I error will increase type II error (other things being equal).
